# remove folder from URL in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I recently asked a similar question, but without the Wordpress context. That was my mistake, and I'm trying this again now.

I'm trying to figure out how to remove **any** folder from the URL generated by Wordpress, and then add ".html" to the end. So:

**Starting URL**: `www.domain.com/ANYFOLDER/any-page-name`

**Ending URL**: `www.domain.com/any-page-name.html`

[This Plug-In](http://wordpress.org/plugins/html-in-category-and-pages/) handles the ".html" part, but I'm still stuck on the folder portion, and both my attempts to handle this directly through `.htaccess` or through an add_rewrite_rule() function produce no results.

Comment: Permalink structure in WP would be the way to go and also see `http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory`

Comment: Can you eliminate parent page folder names through the permalink settings? This is strictly for pages, not blog posts. Heck, I'd be surprised if 1:10 of our clients use Wordpress for blogging :)

Comment: No probably you cannot eliminate parent page folder names through the permalink settings.

Comment: Any assistance with removing pieces of a URL through a regular expression for Wordpress **pages** would be most helpful! We've established what can't be done - is the end result I'm seeking impossible?

Comment: It is probably possible through some plugins but not via mod_rewrite